# knockout: callback function when the content of a template changes

Tags: javascript, html, templates, knockout.js, callback

I am looking to catch the event when the content of a template changes; in other words, after the template is re-rendered each time.

Example:

```
<script type="text/html" id="myTemplate">
<span data-bind="text: myBoolean"></span>
</script>
<!-- ko template: { name: 'myTemplate', afterRender: myafterRenderCallback } -->
<!-- /ko-->
```

In javascript, I simply have:

```
self.myBoolean = ko.observable(true);
```

This observable changes, let's say, there is some other button, clicking on which changes the value of myBoolean.

Therefore, everytime myBoolean changes, the content of the template gets updated. I need the callback function when the re-rendering of the template is completed, meaning when it has changed the value from true to false, or from false to true.

I tried two solutions, but none has worked:

1. the `afterRender: myafterRenderCallback`is only called once, at the beginning when the template is rendered for the first time. It is not called after every time myBoolean changes.
2. Use a listener-like for myBoolean:

   self.myBoolean.subscribe(function() {

   //TODO

   });

The problem with the second approach is that, the subscribe function is called too quickly, even before the template updates myBoolean in the view, and that causes the issue, which is a long story to tell here (I can if you really want to know: for example, in a simple case, I need to access the DOM and the template is more sophisticated than the one above).

I tried another approach by using setTimeout, so to wait 2 seconds or so after myBoolean changes, but that is more like a dirty solution.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

=================================

**Information about the template content as requested:**

So I give you more info here: I have a knockout component, called ToolBar. It is a template; it is just a container with some CSS. Nothing more that that. It contains a set of buttons. Some of the buttons can be visible, or invisible sometimes (let's call that the state of a button). Now, whenever a button changes its state, we want users with disabilities to be able to navigate through the buttons using keyboard only (it's WAI-ARIA), typically pressing tab key or arrow keys.

The problem is, whenever a button changes its state dynamically, it breaks the accessibility by keyboard. The reason for this broken functionality is that the (whichever) technology that controls navigation by keyboard is not aware of the newly changed states of the buttons. Example: Pressing Tab or Arrow keys will just skip the newly visible buttons, or get stuck at the newly invisible one. Or solve this issue, I need to simply refresh the toolbar (there is a function for refreshing) when the DOM has finished the re-rendering so that WAI-ARIA is aware of the final states of all the buttons, and thus enable navigation by keyboard.

The refreshing function, therefore, needs to be called when the whole re-rendering of the template has finished, i.e., when all the buttons have finished changing their states. Thus, I need that event, or a callback to that event.

Relying on the observables (method 2 mentioned above) causes an issue: the subscribe function for an observable is called before the DOM is updated, and therefore the refreshing function is called the DOM is updated too, thus too early, and the keyboard simply operates on the old states of the buttons, and this the navigation is broken.

Please note that there is no async process here. The states of the buttons change simply due to which row of a table is selected, or in a simplified example, let's imagine there is some other buttons somewhere else, click on which change the states of the buttons in the toolbar.

Comment: There is no built-in way to watch for changes to a template as a whole. Once it's rendered you have to watch for changes to individual observables, which is what you attempted to do in your second example. I think we do need some more information about what went wrong in that case. It sounds like you have an asynchronous process somewhere in your template that needs to finish before proceeding so you'll probably need to identify that process and alter it to return a deferred object.

Comment: I just read through your question. I find it hard to decipher your actual use-case from the contrived scenario you outline. I've used knockout since the very beginning, and often when I find myself in situations like this I normally have an architectural problem, not a knockout problem. If you further explain the actual implementation perhaps more sound advice could be provided. Just my two cents of course.

Comment: @PimBrouwers You are right. Sometimes it is just an architectural problem. Just updated my post, added a long explanation. Hope it clarifies things better.

Comment: It looks like I need to listen to DOM change. Just looked up and found MutationObserver. So this may have nothing to do with knockout then. Is there any better solution than this?

Comment: To me, this sentence stands out as containing the answer: "The problem is, whenever a button changes its state dynamically, it breaks the accessibility by keyboard. " -- to me, this suggests you need a Custom Binding, with your accessibility keyboard bindings specified in the "update" function. Which would take the state changing observable (or computed if you're listening to multiple) to REBIND to only active buttons. This custom binding could be placed on the highest level DOM element within the component to give it access to all the HTML it might need to operate.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in my comment above. I believe the sentence:

> The problem is, whenever a button changes its state dynamically, it
>   breaks the accessibility by keyboard.

Contains the answer.

It suggests a "custom binding" is what's needed here. This binding would use the `update` function to listen to the state changes of the observable (or computed if multiple observables are being listened to) in order to rebind the accessibility keyboard bindings.

The code would look like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.accessibilityBindings = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        //keyboard binding code goes here
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to collect all observables that enable/disable/alter your template in one (observable) array. You can then evaluate them in a deferred `ko.computed` to trigger some update/callback function.

E.g.:

```
this.buttonStates = [ this.button1Enabled, this.button2Enabled ];

ko.computed(function someButtonUpdated() {
  this.buttonStates.forEach(function(state) { state(); });
  myCallbackFunction();
}, this).extend({ deferred: true });
```

If you don't want to keep track of which states are in view, you can use a custom binding that registers (pushes to `buttonStates`) in `init`, and deregisters (removes from `buttonStates`) on node removal.

```
<button data-bind="enable: button1Enabled, 
                   register: { 
                     obs: button1Enabled, 
                     arr: buttonStates 
                   }">button 1</button>
```

As you can see, this approach does add some extra code and complexity to your view and viewmodel though... so I'm not sure if it'll work for you. It'll save you from having to implement a MutationObserver though, which might be even more complicated...

Here's a working example:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.register = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var settings = valueAccessor();
    
    settings.arr.push(settings.obs);
    
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(
      element, 
      function() {
        settings.arr.remove(settings.obs);
      }
    );
  }
}

var App = function() {
  this.deps = ko.observableArray([]);
  ko.computed(function() {
    // Create dependencies
    this.deps().forEach(function(dep) {
      dep();
    });

    renderSub();
  }, this).extend({
    "deferred": true
  });

  // Some stuff to mimic an updating vm + ui state
  this.hideAll = ko.observable(false);
  this.count = ko.observable(0);
  this.inc = function() {
    this.count(this.count() + 1);
  }.bind(this);

  // Button states
  this.enable1 = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return this.count() % 2 === 0;
  }, this);

  this.enable2 = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return this.count() % 3 === 0;
  }, this);

  this.enable3 = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return !this.enable1() && !this.enable2();
  }, this);
}


var renderSub = (function() {
  var i = 0;
  return function() {
    // Count renders and show ui is updated
    console.log(
      "Render", 
      ++i,
      Array
        .from(document.querySelector(".tmpl").children)
        .map(c => c.disabled ? 'disabled': 'enabled')
        .join(" ")
    );
  };
}());

ko.applyBindings(new App());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="tmpl" data-bind="ifnot: hideAll">
  <button data-bind="enable: enable1, register: { obs: enable1, arr: deps }">button 1</button>
  <button data-bind="enable: enable2, register: { obs: enable2, arr: deps }">button 2</button>
  <button data-bind="enable: enable3, register: { obs: enable3, arr: deps }">button 3</button>
</div>

<button data-bind="click: inc, text: count() + ' + 1'"></button>
<button data-bind="click: hideAll.bind(null, !hideAll())">toggle</button>
```